# Get the first and last rows in an ordered set grouped by a specific column in one line

Tags: sql

I have a database which keeps track of row counts for every table in different schemas in different databases. These details are updated nightly and keep a rolling 1 year's worth of data for each table.

I need a query that for a given database and schema, I can get the first and last row counts for every table along with the table name and dates.

eg:

The database looks something like this.

```
DateTime          TableName   RowCount
2017/05/22 22:00  TableA      5000
2016/10/12 22:00  TableA      2500
2016/05/22 22:00  TableA      1000
2017/05/22 22:00  TableB      10000
2016/10/12 22:00  TableB      7500
2016/05/22 22:00  TableB      3000
2017/05/22 22:00  TableC      15000
2016/10/12 22:00  TableC      12500
2016/05/22 22:00  TableC      10000
```

I require a result that looks like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TableName | Last Row Date     | Last Row Count  | First Row Date    | First Row Count |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TableA    | 2016/05/22 22:00  | 1000            | 2017/05/22 22:00  | 5000            |
TableB    | 2016/05/22 22:00  | 3000            | 2017/05/22 22:00  | 10000           |
TableC    | 2016/05/22 22:00  | 10000           | 2017/05/22 22:00  | 15000           |
```

I have attempted a number of variations including CTE and a union but just can't get the result I require.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have primary key on this table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Primary key is on [DataBaseName,DateTime,SchemaName,TableName]

DBMS is Microsoft Sequel Server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This query works:

```
select s.table_name,
last_row.date_time last_date,
    last_row.row_count last_count,
    first_row.date_time first_date,
    first_row.row_count first_count
from (
        select distinct table_name
        from history_table 
    ) s,
    (
        select h.date_time, 
            h.row_count,
            h.table_name
        from history_table h
        where h.date_time = (
            select max(h2.date_time)
            from history_table h2
            where h2.table_name = h.table_name
        )
    ) last_row,
    (
        select h.date_time, 
            h.row_count,
            h.table_name
        from history_table h
        where h.date_time = (
            select min(h2.date_time)
            from history_table h2
            where h2.table_name = h.table_name
        )
    ) first_row
where last_row.table_name = s.table_name
    and first_row.table_name = s.table_name
```